# require_once(): Failed opening required on mac os Monterey

Tags: php, macos

I am new to php, and i am trying to set up an existing application on my local, but not able run the application, getting below error,

```
[Thu Mar 17 18:11:28 2022] ::1:49790 [200]: /s4_admin/review_queue/uidlist/ - require_once(): Failed opening required 'administration.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40_4/share/php@5.6/pear') in /Users/rashmi.b/Documents/workspace/simple-stop-spam-service/s4_admin/review_queue/uidlist/index.php on line 8
```

in /review_queue/uidlist/index.php file

```
<?php

require_once($path_services."administration.inc");

$service = new Administration();

$service->get_reviews_uid_list();

?>
```

I am not able to figure this out, as just trying to install existing application.

Application using php version 5.5

Comment: seems like you're missing a file `'/../dao/spamsdao.inc'` Is this in your application?

Comment: I have updated the question by adding code, and yes all the files available which is mentioned.

Comment: Where is `$path_services` defined? Seems that's the issue because the system is trying to include `administration.inc`  without any further path

Comment: Yea this $path_services is defined in config/config.inc and its taking $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; as its value, but why this $path_services is not accessible inside /review_queue/uidlist/index.php ? if i hardcode file path its working.